# How to add breaks in javascript results

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if anyone could tell me how to add something similar to breaks in my .innerHTML.

As it is now, it lists the answers as:

Adding the two numbers4Subtracting the two numbers 0Multiplying the two numbers 4Dividing the two numbers1

All one single line, I was wondering if there was a way to break it up so it looked like list items.

Like this:

- Adding the two numbers 4
- Subtracting the two numbers 0
- Multiplying the two numbers 4
- Dividing the two numbers 1

Just without the bulletpoints obviously.

Here is my code:

Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var e,f;
  function values()
  {
   e = Number(document.getElementById("e").value);
   f = Number(document.getElementById("f").value);
  }

  function MULTI()
  {
   values();
   result = (e+f);
   result1 = (e-f);
   result2 = (e*f);
   result3 = (e/f);
   document.getElementById("MULTI").innerHTML = "Adding the two numbers" +result
   + "Subtracting the two numbers " +result1 
   + "Multiplying the two numbers " +result2 
   + "Dividing the two numbers" +result3;
  }

 </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="cylinder">
   <input type="text" id="e" placeholder="Base..."/><br>
   <input type="text" id="f" placeholder="Height..."/><br>
   <input type="button" onclick="MULTI()" value="Calculate!"/>
  </div>
  <div id="MULTI"></div><br><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put br tags in there since it is html

```
document.getElementById("MULTI").innerHTML = "Adding the two numbers" +result
            + "<br>Subtracting the two numbers " +result1 
            + "<br>Multiplying the two numbers " +result2 
            + "<br>Dividing the two numbers" +result3;
```

Comment: That's what I was assuming but I didn't put the <br> in the quotes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` writes HTML in the element, so use `<br />` as you would writing in HTML:

```
document.getElementById("MULTI").innerHTML = "Adding the two numbers" +result
        + "<br /> Subtracting the two numbers" +result1 
        + "<br /> Multiplying the two numbers" +result2 
        + "<br /> Dividing the two numbers" +result3;
```

Comment: That's what I was assuming but I didn't put the <br> in the quotes, thanks!